# how increment operator works in java

Tags: java, operator-keyword

```
int x=0;
x=x++;

System.out.println("The Value Of X-->"+x);
```

It will print 0 but why?

If we write the following code,

```
int x=0,y=0;
y=x++;

System.out.println("The Value Of Y-->"+y);
System.out.println("The Value Of X-->"+x);
```

Then the output will be 0 and 1.
My question is in my first code first I put the x value to 0 then increment x so the x which value is 0 is replaced by 1,so the result should be 1 but here we got result is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = x++
```

Increments `x` but then it returns its old value.

You should only do

```
x++
```

to increment `x` by 1.

Comment: I think it is - the question does say: ' My question is in my first code' Oops - looks like a mutating question issue (don't you just hate that!)

Comment: my bad, apparently bad formatting was my downfall